# Querying from another Excel or Access database

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, export-to-excel

Hi I currently have two worksheets in an excel file with one of them acting as a database of all the products we sell, with the columns Product ID, Product Code, and Description (sample below).

[image: database sample]

I have another worksheet that acts as a product finder tool, where you would paste multiple Product IDs in the first column and it would return the Product code and Description in the adjacent columns (image below).

[image: product finder]

I currently use an INDEX search to make this happen, but the database sheet has become too big to manage in the same file, leading to severe slow downs. What would be the easiest solution for this? I was thinking of separating the database sheet as an Excel or AccessDB file but I think I will need a lot of VBA manipulation if I do that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *but the database sheet has become too big to manage in the same file* Excel **is not** a software for databases. It's great for calculating but not really good for this kind of stuff if you have a lot of records. I strongly suggest to take your database into Access, SQL or any similar and then connect Excel to it. You could use VBA to query data from your database using DAO or ADO methods. Another option would be, as you said, taking your database into a separate file and querying into it. Check [ctiveX Data Objects vs. Data Access Objects](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/ado_vs_dao.html)

Comment: how big is too big? are you really selling more than 50,000 products? If you can keep the database sheet sorted (by product id) you can use VLOOKUP with inexact match, this is really fast.

Comment: Thanks @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns . Looked up the ADO method. I'm planning to use Access for the DB. Could you tell me if it's possible to give a cell range to the WHERE clause? For eg. something like, SELECT * FROM table WHERE Product ID = A3:A15. This is because multiple product IDs will be searched for at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your data in Microsoft Access using ADO and doing a SQL query to gather data.

*Could you tell me if it's possible to give a cell range to the WHERE clause?*

Yes, there is a trick. SQL commands are plain text, you just need to build it with your parameters. Use the operator [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) in the WHERE clause.

I made a fake dataset as example. Here's my Excel Product Finder (a table named `Table1`):

[image]

Notice I want the info only of products 6,3 and 2. Now my fake database:

[image]

The code to query those specific products:

```
Sub TEST()
Dim cnn As Object
Dim RST As Object
Dim DatabasePath As String
Dim i As Long
Dim Allid As String
Dim Arrayid As Variant
Dim SQLQuery As String



DatabasePath = "C:\Temp\temp.accdb" 'path to database

'Create a connection object.
Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Create recordset object
Set RST = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Open a connection using the OLE DB connection string.
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DatabasePath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

'merge all ID into one single string
Arrayid = Range("Table1[PRODUCT ID]").Value
For i = LBound(Arrayid) To UBound(Arrayid) Step 1
    Allid = Allid & Arrayid(i, 1) & ","
Next i

Allid = Left(Allid, Len(Allid) - 1) 'get rid of last comma
Erase Arrayid 'clean array variable

'specify query
SQLQuery = "SELECT PRODUCT_TABLE.[Product Id], PRODUCT_TABLE.[Product Code], PRODUCT_TABLE.Description FROM PRODUCT_TABLE " & _
    "WHERE PRODUCT_TABLE.[Product Id] In (" & Allid & ") ORDER BY PRODUCT_TABLE.[Product Id]"


'Open a recordset using the Open method
'and use the connection established by the Connection object.
RST.Open SQLQuery, cnn

'copy all data into cells. This will bring full query without headers
Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset RST

'close and clean variables
RST.Close
cnn.Close
Set RST = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

After executing code I get this:

[image]

**NOTICE** that the output **is not** sorted as we had before. We asked the products in order 6,3,2 but the output is 2,3,6!

This is because my SQL query got the operator ORDER BY that sorts by ID field. If there is no ORDER BY clause the output will be sorted as it is in the database stored, not as your Excel.

If you really really really need the output to be **exactly** in the same order that your Product Finder, you can create an UDF function to query each single id once and return a single row for each product but if you work with a lot of data this can consume a lot of time. So think carefully how to approach this part.

By the way, make sure you use the right connection string. You can find many on [Access connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Really appreciate the effort you have put into this. I have been testing this code, but I have ran into some issues. The Product Id in the original database contains values that have digits and letters, like 5754A. So I currently use the short text data type for the column in Access. But when I search for the Product IDs using this code, it returns an error. Could you please tell me why this is happening? It works fine when the values are only numbers in the Product ID column.

Comment: @BigArcade text and numbers are treated different in SQL commands. All text values must be between single quotes, `'text'`. in SQL is not the same `123` than `'123'`. Try replacing `Allid = Allid & Arrayid(i, 1) & ","` with `Allid = Allid & "'" & Arrayid(i, 1) & "',"` so it returns a string like `'value1','value2','value3',...`

Comment: Thanks! It works on the sample data. When I try this on the original data, I get a Type Mismatch error. Could this be because some of the fields have special characters like - (hyphen)?

Comment: @BigArcade it should not. What line does arise the error? Did you try debugging it with F8?

Comment: Thanks @Foxfire And Burns And Burns. Started with a new file and everything is working perfectly now. Also, I initially stored the accdb file locally so that I can just use the file name as path. It seems much more stable when I use the full path. Thank you so much for your help!